# T-SQL Hmac (Rfc2104 SHA2_256) Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography, t-sql, stored-procedure

I'm trying to implement an Hmac in T-SQL using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837547/is-there-a-sql-implementation-of-pbkdf2) as an guide. Please critique this:

```
create function dbo.Hmac (
    @key varbinary(8000)
  , @message varbinary(7936)
)   
returns table
with schemabinding as
return (
    select HashBytes('SHA2_256', Pads.o + HashBytes('SHA2_256', Pads.i + @message)) as [Hash]
    from (values(
        Cast( -- keys longer than blocksize are shortened and keys shorter than blocksize are zero-padded
            case
                when DataLength(@key) > 64 then HashBytes('SHA2_256', @key)
                else @key
            end
        as binary(64))
      , Cast(0x3636363636363636 as bigint) -- Rfc2104 inner padding constant
      , Cast(0x5C5C5C5C5C5C5C5C as bigint) -- Rfc2104 outer padding constant
    )) as Vars ([key], innerPadding, outerPadding)
    cross apply (values(
      -- unrolled loop to XOR key and iPad
        Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 1, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 9, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 17, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 25, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 33, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 41, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 49, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 57, 8) ^ Vars.innerPadding) as binary(8))
      -- unrolled loop to XOR key and oPad
      , Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 1, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 9, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 17, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 25, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 33, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 41, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 49, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
      + Cast((Substring(Vars.[key], 57, 8) ^ Vars.outerPadding) as binary(8))
    )) as Pads (i, o)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks OK to me, without knowing Transact SQL anyway. Some things to consider:

- obviously this implements just HMAC-SHA256, so the function should be named that way;
- the key parameters is 8000 `varbinary` max value. That seems largish to me (although it might not matter much as the size is variable anyway);
- there is no way to perform a hash over multiple fields in the DB which might be a use case (no incremental update possibility);
- similarly, often it is required to reuse the key for multiple calculations, in that case you can cache the `Pads.i` and `Pads.o` values.

I'm also missing some constants being introduced but that might be due to the [nature of TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26652/589259).

Don't forget to test against NIST test vectors, just to be sure.