# T-SQL Pbdfk2 (Rfc2898 SHA2_256) Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography, t-sql, stored-procedure

Using my [previous function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105973/t-sql-hmac-implementation) as a base I've come up the following:

```
create function dbo.Pbkdf2 (
    @password varbinary(8000)
  , @salt varbinary(7996)
  , @iterations int = 1000
  , @derivedKeyLength int = 32
)
returns varbinary(max)
as
begin;    
    declare @hmacLength int = 32;    
    declare @i int = 1;
    declare @l int = (@derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1) / @hmacLength;
    declare @r int = @derivedKeyLength - (@l - 1) * @hmacLength;            
    declare @derivedKey varbinary(max) = Cast('' as varbinary(max));
    declare @u varbinary(8000);
    declare @uA binary(32);
    declare @uB binary(32);        

    while(@i <= @l)
    begin;
        declare @j int = 1;

        select @u = @salt + Cast(@i as binary(4));  
        select @uA = uA.[Hash]
             , @uB = uA.[Hash]
        from dbo.Hmac(@password, @u) as uA;

        while @j < @iterations
        begin;
            select @uA = tA.[Hash] from dbo.Hmac(@password, @uA) as tA;
            select @uB = tB.[Hash]
            from (values(
              -- unrolled loop to XOR uA and uB
                Cast(Substring(@uA, 1, 8) ^ Cast(Substring(@uB, 1, 8)  as bigint) as binary(8))
              + Cast(Substring(@uA, 9, 8) ^ Cast(Substring(@uB, 9, 8)  as bigint) as binary(8))
              + Cast(Substring(@uA, 17, 8) ^ Cast(Substring(@uB, 17, 8)  as bigint) as binary(8))
              + Cast(Substring(@uA, 25, 8) ^ Cast(Substring(@uB, 25, 8)  as bigint) as binary(8))
            )) tB ([Hash]);

            select @j = @j + 1;
        end;

        select @derivedKey = @derivedKey + Cast(case when @i = @l then Left(@uB, @r) else @uB end as varbinary(32));

        select @i = @i + 1;
    end;

    return @derivedKey;
end;
```

I'd really like to replace the loops with something set-based so that I can turn this into an inline-TVF but just can't seem to wrap my head around it...

Comment: Please, avoid posting many questions in a row. Post one, wait until you get an answer, wait a day, and post another one

Comment: @Caridorc I didn't, I merely added a reference to the actual spec in the title of 2 other existing posts when creating this one because I believed it added clarity.

Comment: Sure you did well, my bad, I did not look carefully enough at the main page... Hope you get some nice answers.

Answer (score 2):

I took a very, very wild swing at this. I also couldn't get it down to something entirely set-based, but I was able to get it to an inline TVF with a recursive CTE (two of them, unfortunately). With 1000 iterations, I needed a `MAXRECURSION` of at least 998 to get it to finish.

**I wouldn't trust this as a cryptographically secure implementation**. I strongly suspect that the optimizer could do something funny here that would enable timing attacks; likely some very aggressive query hinting would be needed to ensure a stable join order and methodology. With some digging, I think we would have to do the following (at a minimum) to make it cryptographically secure. All of these are to prevent [timing attacks](https://flak.tedunangst.com/post/timing-attacks-vs-hash-tables):

1. Force `LOOP` joins; `HASH` joins use hash tables, which have known timing attack vulnerabilities, and `MERGE` joins will sort, which will be impacted by the available data.
2. Force a join order (`OPTION( FORCE ORDER )`); if the optimizer knows something about the cardinality of the data set and re-orders as a result we'll also see different numbers.
3. Disable parallelism (`OPTION( MAXDOP 1 )`)

Throughout all of this I'm heavily relying on the behavior of the `APPLY` operator where it evaluates the right-hand side for each row of the left-hand side. This was vital to get some of these complicated calculations, and I suspect is the path towards a non-recursive implementation (if there is one).

The first thing I had to do was re-create your outer loop calculations, which I did with something like this. You might need more in the counter in the middle (just keep `CROSS APPLY`ing to `sys.all_objects`), but this was fine for my test cases.

```
SELECT uAOuter.Hash UA,
       uAOuter.Hash UB,
       OuterLooper.Counter
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength )
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) [Counter],
                @salt + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) AS binary(4)) U
           FROM sys.all_objects
           ORDER BY [Counter] ASC ) OuterLooper
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, OuterLooper.U ) uAOuter
```

After that I got really stuck on how to calculate `@uA` in terms of itself; I still think that there is probably some really, really clever `APPLY` wizardry to get this, but I spent a few hours going nowhere on that one. Instead, I ultimately settled on a recursive CTE to get the base case and then do the calculation.

```
WITH InnerLoopRecursive AS
(
  SELECT tA.Hash uA,
         tB.Hash uB,
         OuterLoop.Counter OuterCount,
         1 [Counter]
    FROM ( SELECT uAOuter.Hash UA,
                  uAOuter.Hash UB,
                  OuterLooper.Counter
             FROM ( SELECT TOP (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength )
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) [Counter],
                           @salt + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) AS binary(4)) U
                      FROM sys.all_objects
                      ORDER BY [Counter] ASC ) OuterLooper
               CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, OuterLooper.U ) uAOuter ) OuterLoop
      CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, OuterLoop.UA ) tA
      CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                      -- unrolled loop to XOR uA and uB
                      CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 1, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 1, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 9, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 9, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 17, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 17, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 25, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 25, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)))) tB ( [Hash] )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tA.Hash uA,
         tB.Hash uB,
         InnerLoopRecursive.OuterCount,
         InnerLoopRecursive.Counter + 1
    FROM InnerLoopRecursive
      CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, InnerLoopRecursive.uA ) tA
      CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                      -- unrolled loop to XOR uA and uB
                      CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 1, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 1, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 9, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 9, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 17, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 17, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 25, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 25, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)))) tB ( [Hash] )
    WHERE InnerLoopRecursive.Counter + 1 < @iterations
)
```

After that I was really hoping to get away with just an aggregate (or maybe a window function), but apparently you can't do that with `varbinary(MAX)`, so I had to do another recursive CTE.

```
, DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT( varbinary(MAX), '' ) DerivedKey,
         0 [Counter]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.DerivedKey + CONVERT( varbinary(MAX),
                                                      CASE WHEN DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter = (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength ) THEN LEFT(InnerLoopRecursive.uB, @derivedKeyLength - ((( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength ) - 1 ) * @hmacLength)
                                                           ELSE InnerLoopRecursive.uB END ) DerivedKey,
         DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter + 1
    FROM DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop
      INNER JOIN InnerLoopRecursive
        ON ( DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter + 1 ) = InnerLoopRecursive.OuterCount
    WHERE InnerLoopRecursive.Counter = @iterations - 1
)
```

Throughout the recursive CTEs the `JOIN`s get pretty funky as we're trying to handle a potential granularity explosion, but it should work okay-ish.

Once we have that final CTE, then we just need to get the result from the last iteration:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Pbkdf2_modified
(
  @password         varbinary(8000),
  @salt             varbinary(7996),
  @iterations       int = 1000,
  @derivedKeyLength int = 32,
  @hmacLength       int = 32
)
RETURNS table
AS
  RETURN ( WITH InnerLoopRecursive AS
           (
             SELECT tA.Hash uA,
                    tB.Hash uB,
                    OuterLoop.Counter OuterCount,
                    1 [Counter]
               FROM ( SELECT uAOuter.Hash UA,
                             uAOuter.Hash UB,
                             OuterLooper.Counter
                        FROM ( SELECT TOP (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength )
                                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) [Counter],
                                      @salt + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) AS binary(4)) U
                                 FROM sys.all_objects
                                 ORDER BY [Counter] ASC ) OuterLooper
                          CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, OuterLooper.U ) uAOuter ) OuterLoop
                 CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, OuterLoop.UA ) tA
                 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                                 -- unrolled loop to XOR uA and uB
                                 CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 1, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 1, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 9, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 9, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 17, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 17, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 25, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( OuterLoop.UB, 25, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)))) tB ( [Hash] )
             UNION ALL
             SELECT tA.Hash uA,
                    tB.Hash uB,
                    InnerLoopRecursive.OuterCount,
                    InnerLoopRecursive.Counter + 1
               FROM InnerLoopRecursive
                 CROSS APPLY dbo.Hmac( @password, InnerLoopRecursive.uA ) tA
                 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                                 -- unrolled loop to XOR uA and uB
                                 CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 1, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 1, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 9, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 9, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 17, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 17, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)) + CAST(SUBSTRING( tA.Hash, 25, 8 ) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING( InnerLoopRecursive.uB, 25, 8 ) AS bigint) AS binary(8)))) tB ( [Hash] )
               WHERE InnerLoopRecursive.Counter + 1 < @iterations
           ),
                DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop AS
           (
             SELECT CONVERT( varbinary(MAX), '' ) DerivedKey,
                    0 [Counter]
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.DerivedKey + CONVERT( varbinary(MAX),
                                                                 CASE WHEN DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter = (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength ) THEN LEFT(InnerLoopRecursive.uB, @derivedKeyLength - ((( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength ) - 1 ) * @hmacLength)
                                                                      ELSE InnerLoopRecursive.uB END ) DerivedKey,
                    DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter + 1
               FROM DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop
                 INNER JOIN InnerLoopRecursive
                   ON ( DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter + 1 ) = InnerLoopRecursive.OuterCount
               WHERE InnerLoopRecursive.Counter = @iterations - 1
           )
           SELECT DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.DerivedKey
             FROM DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop
             WHERE DerivedKeyPerOuterLoop.Counter = (( @derivedKeyLength + @hmacLength - 1 ) / @hmacLength ));
```

Comment: Love the effort and your liberal use of `apply` (my favorite operator). I too got stuck on how to calculate `@uA` in terms of itself and the recursive solution is somewhat clever (I love it, but I hate it!).