# T-SQL Totp (Rfc6238 SHA2_256) Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography, t-sql

Using my [previous function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105973/t-sql-hmac-implementation) as a base I've come up the following:

```
create function dbo.Totp (
    @key varbinary(8000)
  , @timeStep int = 90
)
returns table
with schemabinding as
return (
    select [Pin].s as Pin
    from dbo.GetUnixTime() UnixEpoch
    cross apply dbo.Hmac(@key, Cast(Floor(1. * UnixEpoch.n / @timeStep) as bigint)) [Hash]
    cross apply (values(Cast(Substring([Hash].Bytes, DataLength([Hash].Bytes), 1) as int) & 0xF)) Offset (n)         
    cross apply (values(
        ((Cast(Substring([Hash].Bytes, Offset.n + 1, 1) as int) & 0x7F) * Power(2, 24))
      + ((Cast(Substring([Hash].Bytes, Offset.n + 2, 1) as int) & 0xFF) * Power(2, 16))
      + ((Cast(Substring([Hash].Bytes, Offset.n + 3, 1) as int) & 0xFF) * Power(2, 8))
      + (Cast(Substring([Hash].Bytes, Offset.n + 4, 1) as int) & 0xFF)
    )) [Binary] (n)
    cross apply (values([Binary].n % 100000000)) [Password] (n)
    cross apply dbo.PadLeft([Password].n, 0, 8) [Pin]
);
```

Comment: Hey mate could you provide the other functions referenced for full context?